# Adyen: How do I verify the iDEAL payload in my callback method when an user is redirected back from iDEAL to my web application?

Tags: c#, adyen

I'm trying to implement Adyen with iDEAL as one of the payment methods in a webapplication I'm building. When an user selects iDEAL as the preferred payment method he gets redirected to the iDEAL environment to finish the payment process, I supply a redirect URL which the user is redirected to after he/she completes or cancels the payment. The callback method is called with the following parameters:

```
string payload, 
string type, 
PaymentResultResponse.ResultCodeEnum resultCode
```

The Adyen documentation states I need to verify the incoming payload, which is a HMAC signature.

https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/ideal#integrate-with-api (step 4)

> When the shopper has completed the payment they return back to your website or app using the returnUrl you provided when you made the /payments request. This URL is appended with a payload query parameter which you will use to verify the payment result. If any other parameters are appended, ignore them.

I cannot seem to find which data is used to construct this payload, so I do not know how to generate an expected signature to test the incoming payload against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just received an answer from Adyen support:

> Anonymous (Adyen Support)  Aug 20, 11:48 CEST
>   Hi Jop,
>
> When the shopper returns to your website after an iDeal payment, the
>   payload is appended to the result URL.
>
> You will then need to verify the payload that you received in a
>   /payment/details call (Step 6). In the response you will receive the
>   result of the transaction. In addition we can send you a asynchronous
>   notification with the result of the payment (in case the shopper
>   already closed their browser before the redirect takes place).
>
> There is no need to verify the payload with a HMAC-key. Let me know if
>   you have more questions.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Anonymous
>
> Technical Support Engineer

Answer (score 3):

To make the steps more explicit for future peoples:

### Handle redirect

You will redirect your user to the [adyen endpoint returned in the `/payments`](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/ideal#integrate-with-api) response. Once the shopper completes the payment, they are redirected back to the `returnUrl` specified in the original [`/payments`](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/#/PaymentSetupAndVerificationService/payments) request.

They will be sent to that url with a `payload`, a `resultCode` and a `type`.

- `payload` is an encrypted blob of the payment result object. You will send in another call to decrypt this blob and see the payment result as of that redirect.
- `resultCode` is the result of that payment at that moment. Though there isn't any validation on this redirect, so you shouldn't perform any business logic using this value but instead use the payload or notification of the result.
- `type` is deprecated field. Can ignore as no longer used.

Example return url, payload is abbreviated for example purposes:

```
https://example-site.com/handleRedirect?payload=AAd24...f511%3D%3D&type=complete&resultCode=authorised
```

### Verify the redirect

Submit the `payload` to the [`/payments/details`](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/#/PaymentSetupAndVerificationService/v49/payments/details) to decrypt the payload blob and find the payment result *as of the time of redirect*. The `/payments/details` call **does not query the payment status** but tells you the response contained in the payload.

This step is required as redirects happen in the client space and you always need to consider malicious third parties. A user could manipulate the `resultCode` in the query parameters but the payload object can't be tampered without causing an error.

Include the `paymentData` that was returned in the initial [`/payments`](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/#/PaymentSetupAndVerificationService/payments) call.

```sh
curl https://checkout-test.adyen.com/v49/payments/details \
-H "x-API-key: YOUR_X-API-KEY" \
-H "content-type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "paymentData": "Ab00!B...QABAgAuj", //abbreviated for example purposes.
  "details":{
    "payload":"AAd24...f511=="
  }
}'
```

The response will provide you the payment result as of the redirect:

```
{
  "resultCode":"AUTHORISED",
  "pspReference":"888239265347586D",
  ... //Other payment result data
}
```

Sometimes IDEAL doesn't immediately result in an **AUTHORISED** but a **PENDING** state. This means the payment result is not yet known but you will need to wait for the [notification](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/ideal#ideal-notifications) to know the payment's final result.